# Execute JavaScript function when using jQuery on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, onkeyup

I want to load a function when an on event is triggered.

I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
    function myFunction(data){
        alert(data);
    }

    $(".element").on('keyup', myFunction('a'));
```

I do not want to call the function like this:

```
    $(".element").on('keyup', function(){
         myFunction('a');
    });
```

How do I make this work?
Peter

Comment: why don't you want to call the function the second way?

Comment: @roryok because that works....;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegated version of `on` allows data to be passed as well as the function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".element", 'a', myFunction);

function myFunction(e){
    alert (e.data);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kqLqvgp9/2/

Note: It should be possible to pass data with the *non delegated* `on` handler, but it confuses the `'a'` parameter as a selector and thinks it is delegated anyway.

As `nnnnnn` points out, you can replace the selector with `null` if you do not want a delegated event handler:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kqLqvgp9/5/

```
$('.element').on('keyup', null, 'a', myFunction)

function myFunction(e){
    alert (e.data);
}
```

Comment: Frankly speaking i never knew it...Thanks for sharing.

Comment: To pass data to a non-delegated event handler, you need a `null` placeholder as the second (selector) argument. As indicated in the doco. `.on('keyup', null, 'a', myFunction)`

Comment: @nnnnnn: Handy to know, I have adjusted the answer to include that version. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function myFunction(data){
    return function(){
        alert(data);
    }
}

$(".element").on('keyup', myFunction('a'));
```

You'll basically create a function that always uses *data* to call the *alert* function.

You could also re-use it easily

```
$(".element").on('keydown', myFunction('b'));
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery expects a callback function. You can pass your function as argument like:

```
function my_fx(data){
    console.log(data)
}

$(".elem").on("keyup", my_fx); // data argument will be a jQuery Event object
```

But if you need custom information you can do a closure like this:

```
function make_fx(custom_data){
    return function(jquery_event){
        console.log(custom_data);
    }
}

$(".elem").on("keyup", make_fx("foo"));
```